# Why jQuery map automatically flattened the returned Array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a newbie to javascript and jQuery.
I use languages such like Scala and Python that support list comprehension and Map functions, So I tried Map function in jQuery ($.map(array, func)).

I thought that a basic rule of Map function is the length of output should be the same as the input. However when I tried this:

```
$.map([1,2,3], function(e){return [1,2,3]})
```

I got

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

instead of

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

This seems weird to me.

Can anybody explain this? Thanks.

Comment: That's by design, the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) mentions it, and it's quite useful sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code of `jQuery.map 2.1.1`, there actually is an instruction to flatten the returned array.

```
    // Flatten any nested arrays
    return concat.apply( [], ret );
```

Hence the result.
The jQuery doc also mentions this:

```
 A returned array will be flattened into the resulting array.
```

There is no explanation, however, on why this flattening is performed.

This, btw, creates a significant difference in behavior with the ECMAScript 5 `map` on webkit where

```
[1,2,3].map(function(e){return [1,2,3]})
```

returns

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

ECMAScript 5 support on browsers is available [here](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/) and support for `Array.prototype.map` is very good overall

Comment: That's cool! So basically I can use the Array's function instead of jQuery's one

Comment: Yes but on browsers supporting ECMAScript 5 only check this [resource](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/)